# Parse JSONObject and set them in the view

Tags: android, json

I'm pinging server for `JSON` response. Here is the response what it looks like:

```
{
"notifications":{
  "0":{
     "id":"17546",
     "uID":"6698",
     "text":"Earned 22 points for searching",
  },
  "1":{
     "id":"17545",
     "uID":"6698",
     "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
  },
  "2":{
     "id":"17544",
     "uID":"6698",
     "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
  },
  "3":{
     "id":"17543",
     "uID":"6698",
     "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
  },
  "4":{
     "id":"17528",
     "uID":"6698",
     "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
  },
  "notificationCount":5
```

}
}

I'm getting total notification what I'm receving from the server. How can I use that for my purpose.

I have to parse "text" get `text` and paste it on the view. I was doing it the wrong way. Here is what I have done:

```
JSONObject jNotification0 = jSearchData.getJSONObject("0");
JSONObject jNotification1 = jSearchData.getJSONObject("1");
JSONObject jNotification2 = jSearchData.getJSONObject("2");
JSONObject jNotification3 = jSearchData.getJSONObject("3");
JSONObject jNotification4 = jSearchData.getJSONObject("4");

String jText0 = jNotification0.getString("text");
String jText1 = jNotification1.getString("text");
String jText2 = jNotification2.getString("text");
String jText3 = jNotification3.getString("text");
String jText4 = jNotification4.getString("text");

TextView notificationText1 = (TextView) dialogLoggedInNotification.findViewById(R.id.notificationText1);
TextView notificationText2 = (TextView) dialogLoggedInNotification.findViewById(R.id.notificationText2);
TextView notificationText3 = (TextView) dialogLoggedInNotification.findViewById(R.id.notificationText3);
TextView notificationText4 = (TextView) dialogLoggedInNotification.findViewById(R.id.notificationText4);
TextView notificationText5 = (TextView) dialogLoggedInNotification.findViewById(R.id.notificationText5);

notificationText1.setText(jText0);
notificationText2.setText(jText1);
notificationText3.setText(jText2);
notificationText4.setText(jText3);
notificationText5.setText(jText4);
```

I guess this is not the way I should do the parsing. Please guide me on this.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the notifications are in curly bracets and not in normal bracets? Normal bracets would indicate a Json array, which should make the parsing very easy!

Comment: What do you mean "doing it the wrong way" ? What it the problem? Errors, unexpected results?

Comment: @alkis I only one notification is present then I'm not able to fix them on the view. If I have 4 notification then it is running perfectly fine.

Comment: If I understand correctly then you just need to iterate through the notifications. There are plenty of answers here that should cover you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jSearchData is of the right object then this should work

```
String text = jSearchData.getJSONObject("0").getString("text");
```

You can create a loop for this. Moreover your response has a comma that
is not needed.

```
  "0":{
     "id":"17546",
     "uID":"6698",
     "text":"Earned 22 points for searching"**,** //<-- This comma should not exist  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)? It helps you to parse JSON object to Java object. Your JSON data is a bit weird though. Why the responded notifications didn't get to store in an array but in separate JSON objects?

What I meant is why not:

```
{
    "notification": [
         {
              "id":"17546",
              "uID":"6698",
              "text":"Earned 22 points for searching",
         },
         {
              "id":"17545",
              "uID":"6698",
              "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
         },
         {
              "id":"17544",
              "uID":"6698",
              "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
         },
         {
              "id":"17543",
              "uID":"6698",
              "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
         },
         {
              "id":"17528",
              "uID":"6698",
              "text":"Earned 1 point for searching",
         }
    ],
    "notificationCount": 5
}
```

If you can have something like this, GSON is very easy to use. Create these Java Beans:

```
public class JsonObj {
    private List<Notification> list;
    private int notificationCount;

    public JsonObj { }

    public JsonObj(List<Notification> list, int notificationCount) {...}

    public List<Notification> getList() {...}

    .... get/set methods
}

public class Notification {
    private Long id;
    private Long uID;
    private String text;

    public Notification { }

    public Notification(Long id, Long uId, String text) {...}

    public Long getId() {...}

    .... get/set methods
}
```

Then when you get the Json String, just do:

```
JsonObj obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, JsonObj.class);
```

To get the text:

```
String txt = obj.getList().get(index).getText();
```

Note: you can also get notificationCount by `getList().size();`

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the results and set the text.

```
for (int i = 0; i<totalNotification; i++)
{
    TextView notificationText = (TextView) dialogLoggedInNotification.findViewById(findId(i));
    notificationText.setText((String)jSearchData.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i)).get("text"));      
}
```

Helper function to find ids

```
public int findId(int idIn)
{
    switch (idIn)
    {
        case 1:
            return R.id.notificationText1;
        case 2:
            return R.id.notificationText2;
        case 3:
            return R.id.notificationText3;
        case 4:
            return R.id.notificationText4;
        case 5:
            return R.id.notificationText5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit, I have added the code, that how I was setting up the text in textviews. Can you help me with this?